# Sinatra, Unicorn and Nginx - Proxy multiple Sinatra Apps

Tags: ruby, nginx, proxy, sinatra, unicorn

I have multiple Sinatra apps on unicorn + nginx and I want to proxy the second Sinatra app to be on a `/app` path.

```
root
root/app
```

Here is my nginx configuration file:

```
upstream root {
    # Path to Unicorn SOCK file, as defined previously
    server unix:/tmp/unicorn.root.com.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

upstream app {
    # Path to Unicorn SOCK file, as defined previously
    server unix:/tmp/unicorn.app.io.sock fail_timeout=0;
}


server {
    listen 80;

    # Set the server name, similar to Apache's settings
    server_name root.com www.root.com;
    # 301 redirect http://root.com$requesturi;

    # Application root, as defined previously
    root /var/www/root.com/public;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @root;

    location @root {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://root;
    }

    location /app {
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://app;
    }


    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;

    access_log  off;
}
```

Using the configuration above I get a `404` from the `app` application.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: What URI are you using that gives a 404?

Comment: On the /app page. The culprit was using the absolute url for the secondary app's assets, like `/css/style.css`. I had to use `/app/css/style.css`.